# Can't override OnActivityResult from Renderer

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, xamarin

I'm creating a renderer to open a native Android Activity from a Xamarin.Forms application. In my renderer, I have;

```
public class CaptureBarcodeRenderer : PageRenderer
{  
     private Activity _activity;

     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
     {
          base.OnElementChanged(e);

          _activity = Context as Activity;

          Intent intent = new Intent(_activity, typeof(CaptureBarcode));

          _activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
          //activity.StartActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

I'm using the example from the [xamarin-forms-samples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native) to do this. As might be obvious from the Activity I'm launching, I'm capturing a Barcode. Unfortunately, I am not able to notify the Page that opened this activity that a barcode has been captured. If I can use the result, I can notify the calling page (as I have access to that in here) that we've got a scan and then call PopAsync() from within there.

Because the calling page is a ContentPage, I can't pass it as part of the data in the intent because it's not serializable.

**Question**
How do I handle OnActivityResult when it exists on the Context and I can't override methods for that or subscribe to events.

I want to open the activity for a result, when I get the activity result I want to close the barcode activity I've started and the pop the page off the navigation stack.

Any help?

Comment: Really? A downvote? What didn't I do? I asked a question, I showed what I was working with and where I was stuck .. and I answered the question in the end because nobody was able to assist me with this. If you're going to downvote me for a question that clearly wasn't "I'm too lazy, tell me what to do" at least help me understand what I did do wrong!

Comment: Well, I upvoted you, cos i'm stuck also! ;)

Comment: Where are you stuck with this?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/81305#Comment_81305 This is the thread I started on the Xamarin forums. I found it hard to believe that I was coming across this alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do have this working, but am not really overjoyed at how it worked out.

In my MainActivity class, I created a static property (BarcodeView) representing the page on the forms side. In my custom renderer, I set this variable to the e.NewProperty value.

In my MainActivity I override OnActivityResult

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
     base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
         BarcodeView.DoScan(data.GetStringExtra("code"));
}
```

Now, when I scan, this method is hit. In the Scan Activity, I Finish() the view and then when I get my DoScan() I Pop the navigation to get rid of the custom Renderer view.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem myself, so thanks for posting your answer. It helped me a great deal. I made a slight change since in my case I need other pages to get back activity results. In MainActivity.cs I added this:

```
public class ActivityResultEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int RequestCode { get; set; }
    public Result ResultCode { get; set; }
    public Intent Data { get; set; }

    public ActivityResultEventArgs() : base()
    {}
}

public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    public event EventHandler<ActivityResultEventArgs> ActivityResult = delegate {};

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

        LoadApplication (new App ());
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data) {
        ActivityResult (this, new ActivityResultEventArgs { 
            RequestCode = requestCode, 
            ResultCode = resultCode,
            Data = data
        });
    }
}
```

Then each PageRender can get the results from the events like so:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        var activity = this.Context as MainActivity;

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            activity.ActivityResult -= HandleActivityResult;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            activity.ActivityResult += HandleActivityResult;
        }
    }

    private void HandleActivityResult(object sender, ActivityResultEventArgs e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine (string.Format ("Activity result is {0}", e.ResultCode));
    }
```